# Date in mysql select

Tags: mysql

I have a table A:

```
A.date | A.price
2013-10-01 | 5000
2013-10-02 | 5000
2013-10-03 | 5000
2013-10-04 | 5000
2013-10-05 | 5000
```

and table B:

```
B.date | B.price
2013-10-01 | 3500
2013-10-03 | 1600
```

In output I would like to receive the following information:

```
2013-10-01 | 3500
2013-10-02 | 5000
2013-10-03 | 1600
2013-10-04 | 5000
2013-10-05 | 5000
```

How to do it, help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN, and you can try to join table A with table B:

```
SELECT
  A.date,
  COALESCE(B.price, A.price)
FROM
  A LEFT JOIN B ON A.date=B.date
```

If the join doesn't succeed, B.price will be NULL, otherwise it will have a value. Using COALESCE() you can get the first non null value.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29ec3/1).